# system.xml conflicts if added more than one time

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, system.xml

In my project more than one `system.xml` a file is used for constant variables. I added one field in `system.xml` but it displays other module's field with the one I added.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <tabs>
     <myconf1 translate="label">
        <label>Exotel API</label>
        <sort_order>185</sort_order>
     </myconf1>
   </tabs>
   <sections>
     <tab1 translate="label" module="adminhtml">
        <label>Call Us</label>
        <tab>myconf1</tab>
        <sort_order>186</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>
            <general1 translate="label comment">
                <label>General</label>
                <sort_order>187</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

                <fields>
                    <text_field translate="label comment">
                        <label>Mobile No.</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>188</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </text_field>                        
                </fields>
            </general1>
        </groups>
    </tab1>
  </sections>
</config>
```

How to avoid conflict?

Comment: put code you have tried

Comment: Just change the field name different from previous one. Then there will be no conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. It's a feature.
The `system.xml` files from all the active modules are merged into one big XML before they are parsed and transformed into the system configuration form.
Elements with a certain name, override the elements with the same name from previously loaded files.
This is a nice way of modifying modules behavior without modifying the module itself.
To avoid this, just name your fields differently.